# cython cast char pointer to array of numpy shorts

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, cython

I'm trying to improve on the time taken in adding two fixed length arrays. I must convert 2 strings of bytes into 2 short arrays of fixed length and then add the two arrays together, finally outputting the resultant array as a string of bytes.

Currently I have:

```
import cython
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def cython_layer( char* c_string1, char* c_string2, int length ):
    cdef np.ndarray[ np.int16_t, ndim=1 ] np_orig = np.fromstring( c_string1[:length], np.int16, count=length//2 )
    cdef np.ndarray[ np.int16_t, ndim=1 ] np_new  = np.fromstring( c_string2[:length], np.int16, count=length//2 )
    res = np_orig + np_new
    return res.tostring()
```

however, the simpler numpy only method yields a very similar (better) performance:

```
def layer(self, orig, new, length):
    np_orig = fromstring(orig, np.int16, count=length // 2)
    np_new  = fromstring(new,  np.int16, count=length  // 2)
    res     = np_orig + np_new 
    return res.tostring()
```

Is it possible to improve on numpy speed for this simple example ? My gut says yes but I don't have enough of a handle on Cython to improve anymore. Using Ipython `%timeit` magic I've clocked the functions at:

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.79 µs per loop    # python + numpy
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.77 µs per loop    # cython + numpy
```

e.g:

```
a = np.array( range(1024), dtype=np.int16).tostring()
layer(a,a,len(a)) == cython_layer(a,a,len(a))
# True
%timeit layer(a, a, len(a) )
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 6.06 µs per loop
%timeit cython_layer(a, a, len(a))
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 9.19 µs per loop
```

edit: changes `layer` to show `size=len(orig)//2` orig and new are both byte arrays of length 2048. Converting them to shorts (`np.int16`) results in an output array of size 1024.

edit2: I'm an idiot.

edit3: example in action

Comment: So how are you calling this function?

Comment: What's `chunk_size`? Your code as posted doesn't work... I think one issue is that your `char*` are probably autoconverted from `str` your function being called and then autoconverted to `str` (i.e. unnecessarily copied) before being passed to `np.fromstring`.

Comment: @DavidW sorry, had `to_string()` instead of `tostring()`. I've also updated the python + numpy solution to implicitly use the length of the byte array. are you suggesting that `np.fromstring(char)` would work ? because it converts only the first 48 bytes to short.

Comment: No - I'm just suggesting that it gets converted `char*`->`str`->`np.array` and so it ends up being copied twice. I don't know if that's easily avoidable though.

Comment: Is there any chance you can add a full working example, including whatever benchmark you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to skip the numpy arrays and just use C pointers:

```
from cpython.bytes cimport PyBytes_FromStringAndSize
from libc.stdint cimport int16_t

def layer2(char* orig, char* new, length):
    cdef:
        bytes res = PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(NULL,2*(length//2))
        char* res_as_charp = res
        int16_t* orig_as_int16p = <int16_t*>orig
        int16_t* new_as_int16p = <int16_t*>new
        int16_t* res_as_int16p = <int16_t*>res_as_charp       
        Py_ssize_t i


    for i in range(length//2):
        res_as_int16p[i] = orig_as_int16p[i] + new_as_int16p[i]

    return res
```

Essentially, I create an empty string for the result using the C API function `PyBytes_FromStringAndSize` and modify that. The advantages of that are that unlike your version the both the inputs and outputs are used as is and not copied. Note that the *only* situation where you're allowed to modify Python strings like this is when you've just created an new one using `PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(NULL,length)` - [this is in the C API documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytes.html).

I then get a `char*` to it (doesn't copy the data, just points to existing data).

I then cast the `char*` for both inputs and the output to be `int16_t*` - this just changes how the memory is interpreted.

I then loop over the array doing the addition and using pointer indexing.

In terms of speed, this is about 8 times faster than the Python implementation for short strings (`length<100`). This is largely due to the fixed Python overhead of function calls are creating numpy arrays I believe. For longer strings (`length>=100000`) my version actually slower slightly. I suspect numpy has a better vectorized/parallelized loop for the addition.

---

### Extra notes

Code shown is form Python 3 - for Python 2 you want `PyString_...` instead of `PyBytes_...`

You can get a slight improvement (~10-20%) on your pure Python version by using `np.frombuffer` instead of `np.fromstring`. This avoids copying the inputs.

Comment: Thanks @DavidW - that works an absolute charm. Great explanation too.

For anyone interested I saw a substantial performance increase.

    `%timeit layer(byts,byts,len(byts))`
    `#100000 loops, best of 3: 5.83 µs per loop`

    `%timeit cython_layer(byts,byts,len(byts))`
    `#1000000 loops, best of 3: 438 ns per loop`